# How can I split the path by (".") using python?

Tags: python, json

```
-----------------------mapper-------------------
"contact_information":{
      "person_name":{
         "FormattedName":"some name"
      }
   }   
--------------------current data---------------
client_profile_data = {
   "contact_information":{
      "person_name":{
         "FormattedName":"Abu DND Md"
      }
   } 
}
---------------------changed data------------
profile_data = {
   "contact_information":{
      "person_name":{
         "FormattedName":"Abu DND" 
      }
   } 
}

I need to get the changes of "FormattedName(Field)"  between client_profile_data & profile_data. So I wrote some function in "helper.py"
------------------------helper.py------------------

 PROFILE_FEEDBACK_MAPPINGS  = {
    'FormattedName': {
        'type': 'nested',
        'parent_name': "person_name",
        'path': "contact_information.person_name.FormattedName"
       }
    }


def find_diff(client_profile_data, profile_data): 
    result = []
    for key, value in PROFILE_FEEDBACK_MAPPINGS.items():
        if value['type'] == 'nested':
            try:
                if client_profile_data[value['path'][0][1]][key] != profile_data[value['path'][0][1]][key]:
                    result.append({
                        
                        'current': profile_data[value['parent_name']][key],
                        'changed': client_profile_data[value['parent_name']][key],
                        
                    })
            except Exception:
                continue
    return result
```

----------------Expected output-------------------
changed: "Abu DND"
current: "Abu DND Md"
-----------------Actual output---------
getting none

Can anyone help me? I need a changes from client_profile_data and profile_data so that I define a function initially which will check the type and after that I want to split the path bcz(contact_information.person_name.FormattedName) will give  second if condition will get the differences so that differences will be appending to result. I tried in this way but not working, please help me.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what you are looking for but with minimal changes of your code, a solution coud be :

```
def find_diff(client_profile_data, profile_data): 
    result = []
    for key, value in PROFILE_FEEDBACK_MAPPINGS.items():
        if value['type'] == 'nested':
            try:
                split_path = value['path'].split(".")
                client_name = client_profile_data[split_path[0]][split_path[1]][key]
                profile_name = profile_data[split_path[0]][split_path[1]][key]

                if client_name != profile_name:
                    result.append({
                        'current': profile_data[split_path[0]][value['parent_name']][key],
                        'changed': client_profile_data[split_path[0]][value['parent_name']][key],
                        
                    })
            except Exception:
                continue
    return result
```

You forgot to "split" the path to use it as "keys" for your dictionnaries.